# Measurability of arg function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have been struggling with the following problem for quite a while. The problem asks to show that the function $arg:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}:z\mapsto \frac{z}{|z|}$ for $z\neq0$ and $z\mapsto0$ for $z=0$ is Borel measurable. I have tried arguing that $arg$ is continuous and proceeding from there, but somehow I could not figure out the details. Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be borel measurable, we need to know that the preimage of every open set is borel.

$\text{arg}$ (traditionally) takes values in $(-\pi,\pi]$, so let's fix some open interval $(a,b) \subseteq (-\pi, \pi]$ and see what its preimage looks like. This is perhaps best illustrated by the following picture (if you'll excuse the MS-Paint...):

[image: Preimage of (a,b)]

If the highlighted arc on the unit circle is the arc from $a$ radians to $b$ radians, then the region between the two lines is exactly the preimage of $(a,b)$, since it is exactly points in that region whose argument lies in $(a,b)$.

Can you see why this set should be borel?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for the picture! I think I may get it from there:)